# Can't implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<TestApiWpf.CoinModel>>' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, wpf, webapi

I am begginer developer building a small app using WPF based on info that I get from API. It is quite simple: by passing id I need to return all info that is stored in API.

That is my CoinModel

```
public class CoinModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rank { get; set; }
        public string MarketCapUsd { get; set; }
        public string VolumeUsd24Hr { get; set; }
        public int PriceUsd { get; set; }
        public string ChangePercent24Hr { get; set; }

    }
```

That is the rest of my code. CLient is initialized in separate method

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string txtBoxValue = txtCoins.Text;
            lBox.ItemsSource = GetCoinInfo(txtBoxValue);
        }

        public async Task<List<CoinModel>> GetCoinInfo(string coinId)
        {
            ApiHelper.InitializeClient();

            try
            {
                var response = await ApiHelper.Client.GetAsync($"{coinId}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<CoinModel>>());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

So, as I have mentioned, the task is quite simple, but I run into this error and I don't know how to handle it. What am I missing?

Comment: _await_ GetCoinInfo().

Answer (score 0):

The return value of GetCoinInfo is `Task<List<CoinModel>>`. The property type of lBox.ItemsSource is `IEnumerable`, do you see a problem here? A `Task` is something representing some operation that may complete in the future, not a list. The types are incompatible.

The typical way to get the result of a task (i.e. the `List<CoinModel>` part) is to make the method **async**, and **await** the task. You could also use the `.Result` property of the task to block  until the result is available, but blocking the UI thread is probably not a good idea.